# Need to check how long a user has been registered on my site Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I'am doing a award system on my site, and I want to award badges to users who have been registered for a month, and then years on my website. How would I go of doing this in Laravel 5.2? I already have a created_at on my users table.

[image: My users table]

********** EDIT *****************

Ok so i need to display that in the view, similar to this:

```html
            @if ($user->difference <= 30)
                <img src="{{ ShowSignedUpFor30days }}" class="ui small circular image" id="Badge">
            @else

            @endif

           @if ($user->difference <= 30)
                <img src="{{ ShowSignedUpFor300days }}" class="ui small circular image" id="Badge">
            @else

            @endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you see from your table you can use created_at field to find out when user is created.

You can create a function similar to this in your User model to create badges. (not tested)

```
public function userSinceInDays(){

  $created = $this->created_at;
  $now = Carbon::now();
  $difference = $created->diff($now)->days;

  return $difference;

}
```

You can access to

```
 @if ($user->userSinceInDays() <= 30)
     <img src="{{ ShowSignedUpFor30days }}" class="ui small circular image" id="Badge">
 @endif

 @if ($user->userSinceInDays() >= 300)
     <img src="{{ ShowSignedUpFor300days }}" class="ui small circular image" id="Badge">
 @endif
```

Comment: Just edited my answer. In that case you can get rid of switch statement and return the value.